# What is key in RC.get in R

Tags: r, cassandra

what is key in the RC.get function (`RCassandra` package)?

```
library("RCassandra")
RC.get(conn, c.family, key, c.names,
       comparator = NULL, validator = NULL)
```

in examples I have seen it as "1". Can someone please explain?

Comment: Another question: what is `RC.get` function?

Comment: did you read the help of the function ?

Comment: yes, I have read it. ( help says its row key). My primary key is composed of 3 columns. Seems it will take only one column. I am not sure. What value should i give in place of 'Key'? @etienne

Comment: then maybe use `RC.get.range` or `RC.mget.range`

Comment: Thanks, @etienne,tried RC.mget.range but using   Cas_data<-RC.mget.range(con,"advadslotv2",c("143667","1447443000000","129084"),first = "date",last = "spend",limit = 1000).           It gives error Cassandra exception: Not enough bytes to read value of component 0.